# User.Identity.Name returns blank / empty when impersonate is turned on with valid username and password

Tags: authentication, iis-7, impersonation

We use Windows authentication in our application and in turn uses the Identity info to authorize users based on their membership in AD groups.
To enable DB connectivity, we have enabled impersonation  and provided a valid user id and password. Now in our authorization module, User.Identity.Name returns blank / empty.
Please help. We are using IIS7 for hosting the app.

Answer (score 3):

Did you

1.) turn IIS 7 windows authentication on?

2.) disable anonymous auth, which will take priority over windows auth?

3.) set your ASP.NET auth mode to "windows"?

Comment: i have the same problem :\, any alternative to `User.Identity.Name` ?